# What gamepad has the face-buttons with the lowest actuation force, operating force and/or total key-travel, pre-travel?

Tags: gaming

What gamepad has the X Y A B/triangle-square buttons with the lowest actuation force, total key-travel, pre-travel, operating force?

I found the pro-Nintendo Switch controller has too high actuation force, key-travel for my uses.

Comment: Is this for a Nintendo console or PC?

Comment: Is what for the former or latter?

Comment: The gamepad.... What system do you expect it to be compatible with?

Comment: Nintendo switch controllers are compatible with PC though from my experience (although you do need to manually install drivers)